# Count how many of a certain digit is present on a given number in C

Tags: c

Using a while loop, i need count how many of the first integer (0-9) is present in the digits of the second inputted integer and print the result.

input sample: 2, 124218

output sample: 2

this is my code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a;
    int num; 
    int i;
    int rev = 0;
    int reminder;
    int count = 1;
    int ans;
    int last;

    scanf("%d",&a);
    scanf("%d", &num );

    while(num!=0)
    {
        reminder=num%10;
        rev=rev*10+reminder;
        num/=10;

        if(a==reminder){
            ans++; 

            last = ans%10;
    
            printf("%d", last);
        }
        count++; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why are you printing `last`?

Comment: Your program doesn't seem to print the result (a final value of the `ans` variable). It's also quite unclear what the purpose of calculating `rev` is. Is it _your_ code? Do you have an idea _why_ it is written that way?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
int a, num, remainder, count = 0;

scanf("%d",&a);
scanf("%d",&num );
int temp = abs(num);
while(temp!=0)
{
    remainder=temp%10;
    temp/=10;
    if(a==remainder)
        count++; 
}
printf("%d",count);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wrong main prototype

Comment: it's fixed now.

Comment: It is not. UB for INT_MIN + main still wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
int count_digit(const unsigned digit, int number)
{
    int count = 0;
    if(digit < 10)
    {
        while(number)
        {
            if(digit == abs(number % 10)) count++;
            number /= 10;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        count = -1;  //error 
    }
    return count;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", count_digit(5, 455675));
    printf("%d\n", count_digit(3, -35633435));
}
```

Comment: @CleidNofies it does https://godbolt.org/z/5zfdob1dh Evidence please